# How to temporarily void a key code when an object is in a certain area of the screen?

Tags: processing, keycode

I have a character on screen, who can move left and right using the designated keys but can not move upwards until the character reaches a certain point in the screen(a ladder placed at the end). Once the character reaches this ladder, the user can press UP to climb up, however whilst they are climbing they are also able to move left and right using the keys assigned. Is there any way to make the left and right key command void whilst in the vicinity of the ladder, only being able to go up and then once passed up the ladder, the keys are then usable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the **state** of your character in variables, and then check those variables in **if statements** to take the correct action given the current state.

In your case, you might use a simple `boolean` that keeps track of whether the player is climbing the ladder or not. Then you'd just check that `boolean` when you detect the left or right arrows being pressed, and only move the player left or right if the player is **not** climbing the ladder.

Something like this:

```
boolean climbing = false;

void keyPressed(){
   if(keyCode == LEFT){
      if(!climbing){
         //move player left
      }
   }
}
```